# MySQL select schema without inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I was wondering if there is a simple way to select all values of an entire schema with MySQL, instead of doing it with inner joins?

Tried only using

```
SELECT * FROM ((table_name1 INNER JOIN table_name2 ON table_name1.id = table_name2.id)
    INNER JOIN table_name3 ON table_name3.id = table_name2.id);
```

But stopped because I was hoping for a better solution.

Comment: What's the use case? Relational modeling doesn't make sense this way.

Comment: I just have a script that inserts default values into the database for testing and will see if they are inserted as wished after running the script.

Comment: If no errors occures then all queries were executed successfully andf all provided data was stored.

Comment: You're right, could just be nice to view it. :)